# Using soul and xcolor to highlight \emph renders some letters incorrectly

Tags: color, highlighting, soul

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

    \hl{\emph{irreducible}}
    
    \hl{{\emph irreducible}}

    \emph{irreducible}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: In the firs output, the first "e" is rendered as \varepsilon whereas the second "e" is rendered correctly. This is not an issue if \hl is not used.]

Could you please let me know why the "e" is rendered like a \varepsilon?

Comment: This is due to how highlight is implemented by `soul`. Essentially, when you say `\hl{...}`, it draws a bunch of thin vertical colored lines to create the illusion of backgroud highlight. Sometimes it happens to block part of some letter(s). In your case, that is not an `\epsilon`, but rather just an italic `e` but with its right half blocked (you can see the same blocking with the first `r`, not as severe as the `e` of course).

Answer (score 4):

There is another package with highlighting capabilities: `lua-ul`. Applying it to your MWE would look like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}

    \highLight{\emph{irreducible}}
    
    \highLight{{\emph irreducible}}

    \emph{irreducible}
\end{document}
```

Downside for some would be that it requires luaTeX (or luaLaTeX) for compilation and package `luacolor` for coloring (has to be loaded after `xcolor`, or instead of it of course).

`lua-ul` has also option for compatibility with `soul` (as a drop-in replacement), but I have never tested that. Personally, I would redefine or search & replace all `soul` macros and use `lua-ul`.

As a side note, there are other approaches, like using `tikz` to do highlighting, but I would consider that very advanced process; and it requires at least 3 compilations.

You can find that code in this site, but you will have to (possibly) adapt it to changed hook interface in new LaTeX3 kernel and maybe also some pdf primitives (`\savepos`).

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can overcome by interrupting the normal kerning:

```
\hl{\emph{irre\mbox{}ducible}}
```

by sticking an `\mbox{}` in the middle of a word.  But even that will not work on, for example, ending a penultimate word on an italic `f`.

As a real hacky workaround that could get you out of a bind, you could try this if the problem arises just once or twice in the span of a longer passage.  Note that the argument to `\althl` will **not** linebreak, so it is only to be used for the word that needs help, not the whole passage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\fboxsep=.5pt
\newcommand\althl[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\rule
  [-.75\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{.81\baselineskip}\itshape #1}}
\begin{document}
\hl{\emph{This is an irre\mbox{}ducible test }}%
\althl{of }\hl{\emph{things.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare this to, for example, that which naturally arises just from using `\hl` on the passage:

```
\hl{\emph{This is an irreducible test of things.}}
```

[image]

In this case, the first `r` and the `e` in `irreducible` are clipped as well as the `f` in `of`.

Comment: As I see in `althl` command implementation `\colorbox`, I guess this wont work with linebreaks. If that is true, it might be good to note that in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could use the package `soulpos` (https://ctan.org/pkg/soulpos) which is based on `soulutf8` (which is based on `soul`), but this works even if you don't use the utf8 encoding. But unlike `soul` or `soulutf8`, the package `soulpos` doesn't use repetitives small elements to "decorate" the text. As a consequence, the weird rendering of some characters is gone.

With a modified code from an example in the `soulpos` manual, we can recreate the `\hl` command (here named `myhl`). For comparison, I keep the original code, using the `\hl` command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulpos}

% -.8ex is the depth and 11pt is the height of the rectangle around the text, 
% here for the default size of the text in the article class.
\ulposdef{\myhl}{%
  \mbox{%
    \color{yellow}%
    \rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{11pt}}}

\begin{document}

    With \verb|\hl| from \verb|soul|:

    \hl{\emph{irreducible}}
    
    \hl{{\emph irreducible}}

    \emph{irreducible}
    
    \medskip  
    
    With \verb|\myhl| created with \verb|soulpos|:
    
    \myhl{\emph{irreducible}}
    
    \myhl{{\emph irreducible}}

    \emph{irreducible}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice a slightly more space after the last character in the italic text with the command created with `soulpos`. You can adjust this space with for example a negative value for the option `xoffset-end` for the created command (here, `\ulposdef{\myhl}[xoffset-end=-0.5pt]{%` almost suppress the blank after the last character in the line with the italic word).